# Class extending Number doesn't retain functions after being sent over RPC

Tags: typescript, types, rpc

I have an angular/typescript app that sends JSON data via RPC.

I created a Money class that extends number class below.  When this object is received by my client code via RPC (call to cloud functions), it arrives as a number, resulting in any calls to Money functions resulting in errors that they don't exist.  I attempted to recast the field back into Money, but that didn't appear to work.  Any ideas how to ensure this type is appropriately carried over after being received via RPC?

```
export class Money extends Number {

constructor(amount_pennies: number) {
    super(amount_pennies);
}

public getDollars(): number {
    return this.valueOf() / 100;
}

public getPennies(): number {
    return this.valueOf();
}

public static ofPennies(pennies: number): Money {
    return new Money(pennies);
}

public static ofDollars(dollars: number): Money {
    return new Money(dollars * 100);
}
```

}

Comment: What is the benefit of extending `Number` here?  Why not just have `class Money {...}`?  The issue of serialization/deserialization will be there no matter what (and the solution is to just go ahead and serialize/deserialize explicitly, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wOaoEm)), but there wouldn't be the extra confusion of trying to imbue the primitive `number` or its wrapper `Number` with extra behavior.

Comment: The hope was to maintain number symantics for math and comparisons.  In the end I wasn't able to get that to work as hoped either, but ended up leaving the code as is.

Will I need to call serialize/deserialize explicitly or will typescript call those methods for me itself?

Comment: TypeScript doesn't do much "itself"; I don't really know how your RPC framework works so I'm not sure if there's some idiomatic way to make that framework automatically serialize/deserialize.  If not, you will have to do it explicitly. If you could make your code here into a [mcve] suitable for demonstrating easily (e.g., a link to a web IDE project) then maybe someone could leave a specific answer.